# How to set an Image source to a blank Image control at runtime from selected ListBox Item?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

**PROBLEM:**

I have a blank Image control named "**Image1**".

Now, I want to supply a Source to that Image at runtime base on the selected item on my ListBox (ListBoxSource).

How will I do that in "ListBoxSource_SelectionChanged(...)" event?

```
 private void ListBoxSource_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    //...Some conditional statement in here which determines what image to set or update its Image source

        this.Image1.Source = ??? What to supply in here

    }
```

**NOTE:** I know how to do this using Binding **BUT I know only using another ListBox** to show my selected items. This time I use a **Grid(2 rows and 2 columns:** each cell has a blank Image control in it) for the purpose of supplying each grid cell with the ListBoxSource selected Image item.

**OR** Can I use some binding to this using Grid? My other purpose is also to be able to control the Image in different sizes (meaning some image will span rows/columns inside a Grid).

Here is my XAML:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="{Binding FileFullName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" Width="64"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SampleDataSource}}">
    <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxSource" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" Margin="29,31,0,31" Width="257" SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectionChanged="listBoxSource_SelectionChanged"/>
    <Grid x:Name="GridImageHolder" Height="270" Margin="338,44,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FFE0D6D6" ShowGridLines="True" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=listBoxSource}" d:DataContext="{Binding Collection[0]}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="539">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="130"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="267.883"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="271.117"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image x:Name="Image1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="8,0.96,21.883,8"/>
        <Image x:Name="Image2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19.975,0,0,8" Width="218"/>
        <Image x:Name="Image3" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="8,21.04,40.883,16"/>
        <Image x:Name="Image4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="8,21.04,33.117,16" />

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Comment: you could look at typing e. and hitting CTRL + Space bar and seeing what properties you can get at when you are in design mode you want the SelectedIndex Name of that ImageControl or Image

Comment: What do mean? are you talking about intellisense? Sorry, I only know how to do some bindings..but as to coding, Im a little bit not good at it.. Doing some bindings,..creating XAML ,.etc Visual Studio does it for me..

Comment: you will still have to use some code behind events.. have you searched XAML events in Google..?

Comment: Yes I know..that is why I'm trying to dig a little deeper rather than relying much on IDE..also..I did a lot of research (stackoverflow, google..etc.) but some are in advanced topic..My only concern this time is just to provide the Source of my Image from ListBox SelectedItem/SelectedValue or even SelectedIndex but always come up with an error..mostly "cant implicitly convert this type..etc.."..

Comment: show the exact error .. you many need to append .ToString() to get the name of the selected item.. or from the ListBox[SelectedItem].ToString() something to that affect

Comment: Show the code where you try and cast the sender.

Comment: @DJKRAZE KRAZE Hi,.I tried several times: 

         
    Image imageSelection = new Image();
BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage();
bmpImage.BeginInit();
bmpImage.UriSource = new Uri(string.Format(this.listBoxSource.SelectedValue), UriKind.Absolute);
bmpImage.EndInit();
Image1.Source = bmpImage;

**got error**: cannot convert from Object to string;

Comment: @BalamBalam Hi,.I tried several times: Image imageSelection = new Image(); BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage(); bmpImage.BeginInit(); bmpImage.UriSource = new Uri(string.Format(this.listBoxSource.SelectedValue), UriKind.Absolute); bmpImage.EndInit(); Image1.Source = bmpImage; got error: cannot convert from Object to string;

Comment: Hi, What is your listbox items' type? if it is some class or structure, you should provide an override method of ToString(), which returns the image path. I didn't quite understand what you're trying to do and why you can't do it with binding.

Comment: @Seffix Hi.. Im trying to think about something different in which I can do some custom sizes of my individual image display instead of using template to display with the same sizes, layout..etc.. but of course the items of the ListBox from where the data are coming are bounded to a collection..I just want to display it differently during the selection of item... BUT is this possible to bind and achieve the same thing I wanted to using Grid?

Comment: Read my words.  Code where you cast the sender as in object sender to the event.

Comment: @BalamBalam .. Im so sorry.. I did it finally.. When asking me the "code" to cast I remember to cast it with my class "ImageFound"..and created a new instance of BmpBitmapImage.. Thanks you guys..


     var imageSelected = (ImageFound)this.ListBoxSource.SelectedValue; 
            BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage();
            bmpImage.BeginInit();
            bmpImage.UriSource = new Uri(imageSelected.FileFullName, UriKind.Absolute);
            bmpImage.EndInit();

            Image1.Source = bmpImage;

But im still thinking if this is possible using binding and datatemplate..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the event you need to cast the sender to the appropriate class.

Comment: thank you.. But im still thinking if this is possible to do binding and datatemplate using Grid.. Im just trying to think about something different in which I can do some custom sizes of my individual image display instead of using template to display with the same sizes, layout..etc.. but of course the items of the ListBox from where the data are coming are bounded to a collection..I just want to display it differently during the selection of item... BUT is this possible to bind and achieve the same thing I wanted to using Grid?

Comment: You can bind to the (UI) element in XAML and in the XAML path refer to the SelectedItem.Property.  Search MSDN on Binding Element